# Akka Stream - How to make sure all messages in buffer are flushed to Sink when KillSwitch triggered

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a simple stream with one source, two flows, and one sink. The two flows have a buffer with backpressure strategy attached.

```
buffer(bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure))
```

The stream looks like:

```
source ~> flow1(buffer) ~> flow2(buffer) ~> sink
```

Now, I'm trying to add a kill switch to safely shutdown the stream.

It seems like KillSwitch needs to be injected as a part of flow:

```
viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
```

I have three questions:

1. When I trigger the kill switch, will the source be stopped first so
   that the sink won't lose any messages? If not, how can I make sure
   that?
2. When I trigger the kill switch, will the buffered elements be flushed and successfully reach the sink? If not, how can I make sure that?
3. What part of flow should I insert the kill switch into? Is it
       always right after source? How does the place of kill switch affect
       the stream completion?

The Akka [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#controlling-graph-completion-with-killswitch) doesn't really explain the behavior of the KillSwitch...

Comment: The way I understand it, is that KillSwitch is a flow that procuces useless value for each value received from the upstream and `Keep.right` is used to prevent that useless value to be passed to the downstream. So the moment you shutdown/abort the switch it stops communicating upstream, that newer value should be provided and pass the error/end of stream information to downstream. I would expect that losing upstream buffer content is a case. Basically (if I get it right) it works as if you threw exception in the middle of the stream and made the stream respond to that with materialization.

Comment: Personally I would push the source messages to something like Kafka to make sure they are not lost, and save last processed offset in sink - then I would not miss any message, as on next start I would just run from after the last processed offset.

Comment: That makes sense. Using acknowledgement is a good idea in this case.